# Subclipse/Subversion on Mac 10.9, ANT calling svn info gets back "too old" error

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ant

I have a fresh install of Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2, Build id 20140224-0627.  I used the Eclipse Marketplace to install Subclipse 1.10.  I upgraded the Mac to use Subversion 1.8.8.  Checking "svn --version" confirms this:

svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071)
   compiled Feb 18 2014, 20:15:10 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0

However, with a fresh code checkout in Eclipse, whenever I attempt to run an ANT task (via Eclipse right-click), I get the "This client is too old..." error.  This is not happening with checkout or commits to my code base, only when I am running my ANT task.

The initialization task that runs first in my ANT file calls "svn --info".  If I run this from the command line in the root of my workspace, I get back the usual svn info stuff: repo root, UUID, etc.

However when I run ANT and call svn info from my init task, here is the error message I get:

```
 [echo] svn_info is svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
 [echo] '/Users/<username>/Documents/workspace/myCode' (format 31).
```

I understand the fundamental idea of the message.  But I am under the impression that Subclipse 1.10 was released for Subversion 1.8.8.  Obviously I am wrong.  Can anyone suggest the easiest way to proceed?

Is my ANT "svn info" calling the Mac svn like I think it is? Or is there some other place where I have to set some configuration?  Do I need to install an older version of Subclipse? How do I do that from the Eclipse Marketplace when it always only offers me the latest version?  So many questions, so little time... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when multiple clients for SVN are installed on the same machine and these clients have different versions.
For e.g. 
If you checked your source with Tortose Svn that is version 1.8 now if you try to work with a command line tool like silksvn with version 1.7 you are going to get this error. So basically you need to update the client that is giving this error to it's latest version.

In your particular case the svn tool which probably is (svnant.jar and svnClientAdapter.jar) that your ant script is using needs to be updated to latest. I hope this helps solve your issue:)

Comment: Thanks, but ANT is calling the executable system version (exec executable="svn" and arg line="info") and I don't have the svnant.jar included at all.  Pretty sure that means that the system version of svn 1.8.8 is somehow not as recent as the Subversion 1.10 svn.  That's what's so puzzling, as the docs seemed to say that Subclipse 1.10 is built for svn 1.8.8.  That must be where I am wrong, thanks!

Comment: yes than in your case that's exactly what it means. You need to check the version of svn executable.

Comment: Yes. Apparently I was merely out of synch.  Upgrading svns to all match up nicely did the trick.  Thanks for the help!